# Newly added permission is not upgraded in Android's system app.

Tags: android, permissions, installation, upgrade, reboot

To an application (used as a system app on rooted device) I added: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` in the Manifest alongside corresponding *BroadcastReceiver* which is suppose to start an *AlarmManager* service after reboot.

Then, I updated the system app by using `pm install -r + apk`. However, although I see the version of the app being increased, I don't see the application doing anything after reboot, which is not case when I update the same application but as a user app.

Why the application doesn't upgrade its permissions when is a system app?

Comment: Have you started an activity or otherwise used an explicit `Intent` to invoke one of your app's components? That's required for non-system apps, at least.

Comment: I think that `RECEIVE_BOOY_COMPLETED` does not required user action. This is why you do not see anything. The system should grant the permission silently.